# Anchor Links Not Working from Within the Page

Tags: html, wordpress

My anchor links are working correctly from coming from a different page altogether, but when clicking on the links from within the same page, it takes you too far down below their headings.  The anchor links are submenu items under "Our Work" in the primary navigation.

Can someone shed a little light as to what could be causing this, or offer an alternative solution?

Genesis framework on WordPress 4.7.2.

Comment: What browser? Using chrome v55, I can't replicate the problem.

Comment: So I'm digging through, wondering if maybe it has to do with the ::before content. Working fine in Chrome v55, totally smoked in FF, haven't tried IE.

Comment: First, you cannot provide a direct website links. You have to possible provided a sample code which relates to the problem, but anyway, I've tried to check the site and this issue part cause the issue. I just removed this from the `global.js` and it fixes the issue http://imgur.com/a/enwoE

Comment: Apologies for that - first time poster!  Will remove said link.  I thought the issue might lay within the native js script file.  Thanks, so much - very appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The problem stems from global.js.

Remove it from your code and see what happens.

The script shrinks your header/nav when you scroll past a certain threshold (or in this case, when the anchor link moves your down the page). This is affecting your entire page by shifting it upward; you should probably set the header to position:absolute. You may need to play around with the script some more. Anyways there are many tutorials on shrinking headers on Google.

Secondary issue: You're using duplicate id's in your HTML, which is technically not allowed in HTML. You may never see a problem with it unless you have a script trying to access those id's. Anyways, various browsers may handle this differently, so it's best just to correct it.

For example:

```
<a id="branding"></a><p></p>
<article class="panel" id="branding">
```

should be:

```
<a id="branding"></a><p></p>
<article class="panel">
```

... for all of your sections,

On a side note: You're using `<p></p>` to make visual gaps, however the much better way is to simply use margins and padding rules in CSS.

Comment: That's super strange bc there actually weren't any additional p tags.  I'm thinking this specific framework adds quite a bit of unnecessary html.  Yes, thanks for calling out the duplicate id's!  This has been corrected.  Thanks, all!